# Create curve in modelica

Tags: curve, modelica

I came across a problem when I read a book. In the book, it describes a method to create a curve in Modelica. For example:

```
model Spring
  mechanism.translation...
  ...
  Curve Fscurve(
    x(quantity="Mechanics.Translation.Displace",
      displayUnit="mm"={0,0.06,1}, 
    y[1]mono=0,
      interpol=3,extra=true,mirror=true,cycle=false,
      quantity="Mechanics.Translation.Force"={0,350,1000}
)
  ...
end Spring;
```

Does anyone know the function of `Curve Fscurve`? Where does `Curve Fscurve` come from?

Comment: I would have assumed that `Fscurve` is an object being declared/defined as a type of `Curve`.

Answer (score 1):

`Curve` is not a function. It is a class that is looked up and it is instantiated with the name `FScurve`.

There is no top-level `Curve` available as default in Modelica. So I would say the example in your book either defined `Curve` somewhere or it simply assumes that a class `Curve` exists.

Due to the way [Name lookup](https://specification.modelica.org/maint/3.5/scoping-name-lookup-and-flattening.html) is performed in Modelica, `Curve` could be in the same package as the model `Spring` or anywhere in the path up to the top level.

```
Example 1: Two curves, one local
- Curve
- Mechanics
  |- Spring
  |- Curve    // Fscurve refers to this class
```

```
Example 2: One curve at top-level
- Curve       // Fscurve refers to this class
- Mechanics
  |- Spring
  |- Foo
```

```
Example 3: Two curves, none local
- Curve       
- Modelica
  |- Curve     // Fscurve refers to this class
  |- Mechanics
     |- Spring
     |- Foo
```

The benefit of that mechanism is, that you can use short class names when you are working inside a package and you don't have to type the full class path (but you always can). If you have e.g. an electrical package

```
- Electrical
  |- Ground
  |- Resistor
  |- Inductor
  |- RL_Circuit
```

the example `RL_Circuit` could look like that:

```
model RL_Circuit
  Ground ground;
  Resistor R1;
  Electrical.Resistor R2;  // refers to the same class as R1, but using its full name
  Inductor L1;
equation
  connect ...
end RL_Circuit;
```